# How to record multiple goals in score-keeping app?

Tags: usability, gui-design, input-fields, sliders

The image below shows an application for creating football (soccer) match reports, specifically the section for recording the goals scored.

Note: This UI is for *recording scores after the game*, not during it.

[image]

1. If the match result is 0:0 should I use on/off slider button to disable the area, or should I remove it and let the user leave this area empty?
2. If one player scored more than one goal, should I separate the data like it is under "Home team", or should I do it like it is under "Away team"?
3. Should the all UI-elements of the right side of Fullname-text box be bellow it instead?
4. Some other suggestions?

Comment: The name of the team and the name and number of each player is loaded on the system just once, or everything you have to register a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show/hide toggle and the multiple sets of inputs for recording the same type of data seem inefficient.

You can save on UI by only having one set of inputs and letting the user specify if the goal is for home or away.

User simply starts recording goals, and as they are saved they populate the area below the input UI.

1) If 0-0 - Don't hide the UI behind a slider and make the user find it. Make it easy for a first time user to see where goals are recorded, and for an experienced user to start recording quickly. If there are no goals, it simply stays blank. Aside from saving some space in your layout, there is no significant benefit to using this element.

2) If multiple goals - This should really depend on how this data is going to be used. If it's important that it be easy to quickly read and parse the info, then separate into individual entries. If that's not so important, it's probably ok to have the entries on the same line i.e. '16, '55, '89PK etc.

I've chosen to use individual lines in the wireframe because I think it the clearest, and gives the best experience for both reading and input (e.g. If I'm recording the 6th goal of a game in which there are more than one goal by more than one person, it's easy for me to quickly look at the display and see which goals have already been recorded and which haven't)

3) Beside or below - this is just layout. Worry about that when you've sufficiently streamlined the interaction.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjBQ45.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Player numbers are already in the database so that filed we don't need here but instead we actually need "Assist by" with name and minutes. In this case we just need  a little to change the lay out but Yes, one set of inputs looks right.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If the match result is 0:0 should I use on/off slider button to disable the area or should I remove it and let the user to leave this area empty?

In my opinion it is good to keep the slider button. The interface will be more clear. But I would think about the header. Maybe "Did anyone score?" would be better then "Who scored?"

Or if user has to complete the final score before, you can replace slider with automated action. If the score is different that 0:0 then show the "who scored" module. Otherwise hide it.

> 2. If one player scored more than one goal should I separate the data like it is under "Home team" or should I do it like it is under "Away team"?

For me the "Home team" version is better. You don't have to advice the user about the field format "Fullname + minutes".

> 3. Should the all UI-elements of the right side of Fullname-text box be bellow it instead?

I like it like it is now. It looks more clear.

> Some other suggestions?

I don't know how accurate are your reporters but maybe it would be useful. Sometimes there are situations when player scores in additional time. E.g. 45'+2